# VBA Copy from Excel and replace all in Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have been troubleshooting this issue for a couple of weeks, in addition to looking for solutions on Google as well.

Scenario: I am looking to copy a string of text (ABC Company) from a particular Excel cell (Range "B2") and replace the text (Company_name) several times in Word. Thinking of storing this string in a variable (Coy_name) and running a 'Replace All' instruction. The codes are below:

```
Sub CopyDataToWord()

Dim appWd As Word.Application
Dim wdFind As Object
Dim docWD As Word.Document
Dim CoyName As String

Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWd.Visible = True
Set docWD = appWd.Documents.Open("D:\Dropbox\ClassSheet.docx")

sheet1.Range("B2").Copy

'Some code which will input the string from "B2" into variable Coy_name

appWd.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
appWd.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With wdFind
    .Text = "Company_name"
    .Replacement.Text = Coy_name
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
appWd.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Set appWd = Nothing
Set docWD = Nothing
Set appXL = Nothing
Set wbXL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Some of the origins from the codes came from other materials which I piece together, so they may look out of place. Do shoot me questions if I may have been careless in explaining what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
sheet1.Range("B2").Copy
```

Do this:

```
Coy_name = sheet1.Range("B2").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Going to give it a try now :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Appreciate your effort David!

Comment: I used this code but getting an stating object variable or with block variable not set